# Doob-Kolmogorov Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Denote by $(X(t),t\ge 0)$ a standard Brownian motion, i.e random variables with the following properties:

1. $X(0)=0$.
2. With probability 1, the  function $t\mapsto X(t)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.
3. For $0\le r<t$, we have  $X(t)-X(r)$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $t-r$.

Define $X(s)=\sup_{0\le t\le s} |X(t)|$. 
Prove that
\begin{equation}
P(X(s)\ge \delta) \le \frac{s}{\delta^2}.
\end{equation}

My attempt is the following:

By no. 3 $E[X(s)]=s$. Thus, the problem can be reduced to show that
\begin{equation}
P(X(s)\ge \delta) \le \frac{E[X(s)]}{\delta^2}.
\end{equation}
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like you already solved it. What help do you need?

Comment: The definition

$$X(s) = \sup_{0 \leq t \leq s} |X(t)|$$

is rather confusing (note that $X(s)$ already has a meaning - it is the Brownian motion at time $s$!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Doob's maximal inequality

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{s \leq t} |M(s)| \geq \delta \right) \leq \frac{1}{\delta^p} \mathbb{E}(|M_t|^p), \qquad \delta>0,$$

which holds for any continuous martingale $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ such that $M_t \in L^p$, $p \geq 1$.